# Help with inferring max current ratings for these components

Tags: datasheet

Where is the max output current mentioned for [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1006.pdf) opamp? What does "Million Min" mean in this context?

And where is the max base current is mentioned for [this](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF) transistor?

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect the opamp to maintain spec operating at "non-zero" currents

[image]

> Guaranteed High Gain
>
> 5mA Load Current: 1.5 Million Min
>
> 17mA Load Current: 0.8 Million Min

means the gain is at least that many million (at a minimum)

---

For NPN max base current, there is little point exceeding the base current that saturates the collector current, even if it doesn't overheat. The collector current should be dominating the heat dissipated anyways. Base current should be miniscule in comparison.

Comment: You gave no estimate value.

Comment: @user1999 Because they are rather irrelevant if you are using the component properly. The parts are out of spec if you use them at maximum heat dissipation due to base current or opamp output current.

Comment: Same thing can be said for the max collector current as well  but they still mention it.

Comment: No, same thing cannot be said, because the collector current dominates over the base current. If you get 1000x collector current for each unit of base current, why would heat dissipation due to base current ever be the limiting factor? Unless you just had an open collector and were just pumping in as much base current as possible but that circuit does nothing.

Comment: @DKNguyen, BJTs can also operate in saturation, then the base current might be similar or even higher than the collector current. (OP, I think in this case you'd need to figure the base current limit from the power dissipation limit)

Comment: @ThePhoton But why would you ever drive it with significantly more base current than would be required to produce 200mA of collector current?